# What tutorial videos is best for numerical methods 1?

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm doing this course and we have only been told to work through the prescribed textbook. No study guide was given and I'm not sure how/where to start with the assignment questions. Please advise.

Comment: What about reading the textbook?

Comment: Numerical methods 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is hard to say what is best as different things work for different people, but you might want to peruse and think about the following items.

**Open Courseware**

- [*MIT OCW Intro NA*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-330-introduction-to-numerical-analysis-spring-2004/index.htm)
- [*First Order ODEs*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/numerical-methods/)
- [*MIT Open Courseware List of NA Courses*](http://search.mit.edu/search?site=ocw&client=mit&getfields=*&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=http%3A%2F%2Focw.mit.edu%2Fsearch%2Fgoogle-ocw.xsl&proxyreload=1&as_dt=i&oe=utf-8&departmentName=web&filter=0&courseName=&q=numerical+methods&btnG.x=-1074&btnG.y=-105)
- [*Open Courseware Consortium NM*](http://www.ocwconsortium.org/index.php?option=com_coursefinder&view=search&uss=1&Itemid=9&q=numerical+methods&l=English)
- [*Introduction to Numerical Methods*](https://www.udemy.com/numericalmethodsguy)
- [*Holistic Numerical Methods - Transforming Numerical Methods Education for the STEM Undergraduate*](http://nm.mathforcollege.com/)
- [*Numerical Analysis - Numerical Methods (Not Videos)*](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/numericalundergradmod.html)

**Other Books**

- See my answer here: [Numerical Methods Texts, mid-level.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427654/numerical-methods-texts-mid-level)
- Numerical Methods for Scientists and Engineers, Hamming
- Numerical Methods that Work, Acton
- Peruse your college library for others that suit your needs

**Other References**

- Look for questions/answers on MSE or ask new ones.
- Online Notes for particular topics

Comment: +1 Dear Amzoti, do you know how can I give part of my reputation so someone here? Thanks

Comment: Awesome collection! Thanks for posting it +1

Comment: @amWhy: IIRC Math Type uses a CAS (maybe Maxima) as the back end for doing calculations. It is a wonderful idea and can be a very nice tool with an interactive environment for writing/authoring papers/research. I think it can also export to all sorts of formats.

Comment: I agree...I loved the original, and for many years, into adulthood, I had to leave the room when the wicked witch and the flying monkeys captured Dorothy!! I couldn't bear to watch (even knowing that Dorothy always triumphed!) I still wince when I recall toto being taken!